# Getting height and width of swf file before loading- as2

Tags: flash, actionscript, progressive-download

I am implementing progressive loading of swf document file. For this I need height and width of the swf frames while loading the document.

I have tried

```
mclListener.onLoadProgress = function (target_mc, numBytesLoaded, numBytesTotal)
{
    swfwidth = target_mc.width;
    swfheight = target_mc.height;

};
```

But this returns value 0. I know these values work well with mclListener.onLoadInit() but I want the width and height while loading the document. Is there any possible way?

Comment: I got this question for help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937472/how-can-i-get-the-width-height-of-a-loaded-swfs-stage-in-as2
But don't know how to create movieclip for one frame of swf.